# Como acessar o banco de dados diretamente da minha classe modelo num projeto ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

No ASP.NET Core Mvc eu consigo ter acesso ao DbContext no Controller através da propriedade `_context` representada pela minha classe `MvcNotaContext` veja:

```
private readonly MvcNotaContext _context;
```

Desta forma eu posso efetuar uma busca no banco de dados na classe controladora:

```
var nota = await _context.Nota.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
```

Entretanto, eu possuo uma regra de negocio no meu modelo que necessita obter alguns dados diretamente da base de dados para efetuar a validação, mas, eu não sei como eu poderia obter uma instancia da minha classe `MvcNotaContext` diretamente na minha classe modelo `Nota`, e esta classe necessita das opções de configuração `DbContextOptions<MvcNotaContext> options` para funcionar, sendo que ela é usada no método `ConfigureServices` na classe `Startup` de inicialização:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddDbContext<MvcNotaContext>(options => options.UseSqlite("Data Source=MvcNota.db"));
}
```

Minha classe modelo:

```
public class Nota: IValidatableObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }       
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Titulo não pode ficar vazio.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name="Título")]
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Conteúdo não pode ficar vazio.")]
    [Display(Name="Conteúdo")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Conteudo { get; set;}

    IEnumerable<ValidationResult> IValidatableObject.Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        //Busca dados na base de dados.
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

O acesso ao banco ocorreria no método `Validate`, respectivamente.

---

## Pergunta

Como eu posso acessar a base de dados diretamente da minha classe modelo (model) em um projeto ASP.NET Core Mvc?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem. A classe Nota é um model ou uma entidade?

Comment: Pode considerar como um Model.

Comment: Se é um model, posso considerar que você esteja utilizando como uma ViewModel junto ao Razor?

Comment: Neste caso não é um ViewModel, é só o Model que representa a tabela nota no meu banco de dados.

Comment: É essa classe que você utiliza no seu DbSet para configurar seu banco?

Comment: Sim exatamente, só tem esta classe. O banco é só uma tabela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só você criar uma instância do contexto neste método, exatamente como faria com qualquer outro objeto

```
IEnumerable<ValidationResult> IValidatableObject.Validate(ValidationContext vCtx)
{
    var optBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MvcNotaContext>();
    optBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=MvcNota.db");
    var context = new MvcNotaContext(optBuilder.Options);
}
```

<sup>Obs.: Mudei o nome do parâmetro só pra encurtar o código.</sup>

Pra isso, obviamente, você precisa se certificar de que há um construtor de `MvcNotaContext` que receba uma instância de `DbContextOptions<T>` como parâmetro.

```
public MvcNotaContext(DbContextOptions<MvcNotaContext> options) : base(options) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instanciar um contexto dentro da sua classe de modelo (que representa uma tabela no banco) não é um padrão interessante, a obrigação do domínio é apenas se validar, e para isso você não precisa fazer uma instancia direta com o banco. Não é uma boa prática uma camada mais interna como a de domínio ser acoplada com uma Unidade de Trabalho.

Se você quer comparar um valor previamente inserido no banco de dados com um novo objeto, faça a consulta antes na sua camada escolhida (recomendo que faça isso em uma camada de serviço) e passe ela como argumento para sua classe de validação, algo como:

```
var minhaNotaConsultadaDoBanco = await _context.Nota.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
```

Agora na sua model:

```
IEnumerable<ValidationResult> IValidatableObject.Validate(Nota minhaNotaConsultadaDoBanco)
{
    //Exemplo:
    if(this.Titulo != minhaNotaConsultadaDoBanco.Titulo) { ... }
}
```

Caso queira inserir um objeto totalmente novo e fazer o double check, você pode usar a própria instância para chamar o método de validação.

```
IEnumerable<ValidationResult> IValidatableObject.Validate()
{
    //Exemplo:
    if(this.Titulo != string.Empty) { ... }
}
```

Chamada:

```
minhaNotaConsultadaDoBanco.Validate();
```